# Jquery Flot chart with months in X axis

Tags: jquery, flot

I have the code bellow to draw a chart. I want show in the X axis the month/year but, when I run the application, it shows me just the first month. How can I show anothers month ?

```
    var data1 = [
        [0, 4], [1, 8], [2, 5], [3, 10], [4, 4], [5, 16], [6, 5], [7, 11], [8, 6], [9, 11], [10, 30], [11, 10], [12, 13], [13, 4], [14, 3], [15, 3], [16, 6]
    ];
    var data2 = [
        [0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 0], [4, 1], [5, 3], [6, 1], [7, 5], [8, 2], [9, 3], [10, 2], [11, 1], [12, 0], [13, 2], [14, 8], [15, 0], [16, 0]
    ];
    $("#flot-dashboard-chart").length && $.plot($("#flot-dashboard-chart"), [
        data1, data2
    ],
            {
                series: {
                    lines: {
                        show: false,
                        fill: true
                    },
                    splines: {
                        show: true,
                        tension: 0.4,
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        fill: 0.4
                    },
                    points: {
                        radius: 0,
                        show: true
                    },
                    shadowSize: 2
                },
                grid: {
                    hoverable: true,
                    clickable: true,
                    tickColor: "#d5d5d5",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    color: '#d5d5d5'
                },
                colors: ["#1ab394", "#464f88"],
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "time",                        
                    minTickSize: [1, "day"],
                    timeformat: "%b/%y"
                },
                yaxis: {
                    ticks: 4
                },
                tooltip: true
            }
    );
```

**Rendered Chart**

[image]

If I remove all the options from `xaxis` (i.e. `xaxis: { },`), in the rendered chart some points appears on the X axis.

**Rendered Chart without options on xaxis**

[image]

Comment: @RachelGallen if I let empty all the options inside the xaxis, some points appears in the rendered chart like I show in my updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do either:

xaxis: {ticks: [[1, Jan], [2, Feb], [3, Mar]} etc..

or try adding

```
axisLabel: "Date",
axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
axisLabelPadding: 10
```

Read more [here](http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-stacked-chart.html#OCgj1vZD27EoirHl.99)

Comment: Just in case you don't want to type it:

xaxis: {
                        ticks: [[1, "Jan"], [2, "Feb"], [3, "Mar"], [4, "Apr"], [5, "May"], [6, "Jun"], [7, "Jul"], [8, "Aug"], [9, "Sep"], [10, "Oct"], [11, "Nov"], [12, "Dec"]]
                    }